# How to get the id of a row from the html table.so that I can delete that row from data base

Tags: javascript

How to get the id of a row from the html table.so that I can delete that row from data base..

```
var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
```

I used this to get the row id , but I can't use this id for deleting the row from the database.

```
            <tbody>
    <%  while(rs.next()){%> 
    <tr id="<%=rs.getString(1)%>">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                <td id="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Delete Student" name="delete" onclick="deleteRow(rs.getString(2))"/></td>


         </tr>
```

---

Comment: Post your code how you tried to remove it by id please

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: Add an ID column in database, and make it Auto_increment.
Echo this id as row id for html table. for deleting a particular row send this particular row id to server to delete that row from databse and of course you can also delete it as userside by the method you used above

Comment: Give more info, otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: I used this code....                                                    <script>function deleteRow(tableID) {
                       var table= document.getElementById(tableID);

            table.parentNode.removeChild(table);
            document.write(table);
                   ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from tb_validation where id="+'"document.getElementById(tableID)+"');
                 
                  ps.executeUpdate();
                
        }
 </script>